# How to call two functions in a sequence, where one is a Volley function?

Tags: android, sqlite, function, sequence, android-volley

I have two functions in my code, one is a Volley function and another is normal SQLite function. The problem I am having is the sequence of the execution. Before I get the response from the Volley function, the SQLite function is called an executed. How can I delay the execution of the SQLite function until Volley sends the response back?

```java
up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       { 
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               //toSpeak.
              //  Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               View parentView = (View) v.getParent();
               Drawable drawable = up.getDrawable();

               if(drawable.getConstantState().equals(up_green.getConstantState()))
               {
                int postid= Integer.parseInt(((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.post_id)).getText().toString());

                    sendVote(postid,"RU");

                  int points =db.getLocalPoints(postid);
               }
           }
       });
```

The problem here is `sendVote`, the Volley function, and I want to wait for its response and then execute the call for the SQLite function `getLocalpoints`. But `getLocalPoints` is called first before the response from the Volley `sendVote` function arrives.

Comment: check the edit now..and let me know some solution please. Thanks @CL.

Comment: You have to call `getLocalPoints` from the response listener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Volley has a feature called "future" that you can use, to "wait" for the Volley call, before proceeding. To use it, do something like this:

```
        final RequestFuture<string> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        final FileListRequest request = new FileListRequest(Request.Method.GET, theURL, future, future);
        queue.add(request);
        //WARNING: will block!
        final String response = future.get();

        // Proceed with your SQLLite code here....
```

I am assuming you will be executing this code(s) in an AsyncTask, else your UI will freeze...

Comment: Can you explain how to use it in my problem ? I am new to volley so do not much about the execution.

Comment: Show your code, that calls the Volley function(s). Is it inside the "sendVote" method?

Comment: yeah the sendVote is the volleyfunction in my code...and getLocalPoints is the sqlite function.

Comment: So can you show your sendVote code, and maybe your response listener?